# CS Cart 4 How to assigned a variable to a tpl file

Tags: variables, smarty, assign, cs-cart

I want to show our users there Country Code, on the Product Page in our CS-Cart Store.

I have tried `{$user_data.b_country}` what didn't work.

Smarty Debug Console also does not show this information so I guess I have to assign this  variable to the `view.tpl` File first.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try:

```
{$cart.user_data.b_country}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work i tried it already, the variable is not passed to the template according to the {debug} :-(

Comment: So maybe you should first check what variables are visible in Smarty. You should in PHP run `$smarty->debugging = true;` and new windows should be opened with variables that are assigned from PHP

Answer (score 0):

Before you call the variable on tpl you need to assign to array variable $user_data
b_country is part of a profile and the customer can have multiple profile

Script bellow will take the b_country from primary profile

1.
add file

```
app/addons/my_changes/init.php
```

with content

```
<?php

if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

fn_register_hooks(
    'sucess_user_login'
);
```

2.
add file

```
app/addons/my_changes/func.php
```

with content

```
<?php

if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

    function fn_my_changes_sucess_user_login(&$udata, $auth){
        if(!isset($auth['b_country']) && $auth['user_id']>0){
            $auth['b_country'] = db_get_field('SELECT b_country FROM `?:user_profiles` WHERE user_id = ?i AND profile_type = ?s', $auth['user_id'], 'P');
        }   
    }
```

3.
now you can use in tpl

```
{$auth.b_country}
```

I hope that helps